# Map and sets in java

Tags: java

I know about collections. But i was thinking , when we overide the key in map , it simply overides the previous value assigned to it.

On the otherside , we say that when we put value in map it calls hashcode() and if it goes to same bucket then equal() is been called. In case not , there is no need to call equal() method.

If thats the case, when we overide the key in hashmap. It probably calls hashcode() and as if same hashcode is returned for key/value pair. Then equal is been called and after checking that its exactly same , why it gets overide??

Comment: Uh, no, a map implementation does not need to call `.equals()` or `.hashCode()` on values at all... There _is_ a `.containsValue()` method but save for some very specific implementations it will just walk all the entries to find the value. Note that while keys are unique, values have no such requirement.

Comment: Also note that there are maps and sets whose uniqueness contract _is not_ based on `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`; for instance, `Tree{Set,Map}` and `IdentityHash{Set,Map}`.

Comment: what happens in case of Set?? Do they get override?

Comment: No, they don't get inserted at all (this is why a set's `.add()` method returns a boolean). Just like keys in a map aren't replaced, only values associated with that key are.

Comment: "Then equal is been called and after checking that its exactly same , why it gets overide??" Because that's what maps are supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i am talking about HashMap ...did they even dont call hashcode() and equal()

Comment: They do but for _keys_, not values. Note that a `Map` is a set of `Map.Entry` objects.

Comment: So , u mean values gets overide not keys in maps. I can say that , in hashmap the keys are checked by using hashcode() and equal() method. However the associated value are checked through .containsValue()

Comment: I still can't tell what this question is asking, but...yes, it checks that the keys have the same hash code, and then checks if they're equal, and after that it overwrites the old value with the new one.  The "associated value" isn't really checked at all in a `put` call, but when you call `containsValue`, it uses the `equals` method on the values.

Comment: suppose the keys are equal then who let them overwrites the value? is that .containsValue() method?

Comment: If the keys are equal then it won't do anything with the value, except put it in the bucket. It won't call any methods on the value.

Comment: i got it . Thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

The HashMap (and map implementations) do not call hashCode() method on the values - they are called on the keys. There is a check performed to see if the key is null - if this is the case, hashCode() is not called and the key is stored in position 0 in the map's table.

The hash function is called on the keys. We all know that a map retrieves elements in constant time O(1). Now comes the interesting part - it is not always the case that the hash code of a key resolves to a unique value. When the number of entries is large, the HashMap in java applies another hashing function to resize the map structure but this cannot be done infinitely. At a certain point, more than one key will resolve to the same value. In this case, when more than one key gets hashed into the same bucket(location within the map structure), the collision is resolved by storing the elements as a linked list (this happens very rarely). Now the look up time for an element that has gone into a bucket which points to a linked list is linear (O(n)).